# WebGrid in MVC 5 with server side processing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

I am working on a new asp.net mvc-5 web application, and i have search for a web grid that can provide these main features:-

- sort.
- filter.
- search.

  after doing a search for around 2 weeks , i did not find any web grid that is 100% designed to work with asp.net mvc 5, as most of the grids will prevent me from benefiting from the asp.net mvc main features such as:-
- using html helpers such as `Html.DisplayNameFor` , as in most web grids i need to manually write the table header labels.
- using data annotation. as most of the grids will work directly with json returned from action methods, so any data annotations are going to be ignored.

Today I found the  asp.net MVC web grid http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

But I have these two questions:-

- can anyone adivce about using the asp.net MVC web grid ? and what are the main features i can benefit from?
- is there any documentation about how to use the WebGrid inside the following; asp.net mvc5 + Razor view + using server side (not client side) to implement filtering, sorting and search ?

Can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks.

Comment: All of the information used in `DisplayNameFor` and data annotations can easily be extracted and sent back with the JSON. Any reason you don't want to do this? Also, many of the grids I've seen let you statically initially the grid and then update the data via Ajax or some other method. The static initialization can be done in a Razor view. I've also seen grids that use Ajax to do server-side processing. Nothing's 100% perfect, so be willing to do a little bit of glue work.

Comment: I am; myself, am becoming acquainted with the WebGrid but for a while, I've had great success with datatables.net, which offers sorting, paging and search filtering. As mentioned though, you must be willing to do a little work to blend it nicely with your application. Datatables offers ajax integration for server-side processing. You might also look at datatables.mvc which basically helps datatables place nicely with MVC https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.mvc

Comment: @siride can you adivce more on your point, and how i can benefit from data annotations and html helpers when using web grids. second question which web grid/s you adivce to you with asp.net mvc ?

Comment: @codeman061988 thanks for the reply, i will try the datatables.mvc, but seems it lack documentation ? can you adivce if there are full documentation about this grid?

Comment: @johnG Though [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) article is for WebGrid for MVC3, it may help you extend to your exact requirement.

Comment: @SivaGopal can you adivce if you have used this before inside asp.net mvc project ?and the link you provide is written on 2011 which seems a bit old? can you adivce ?

Comment: @johnG I have used WebGrid way back in MVC3. Though the article looks dusted by age :) but still most of it should be valid with latest one. You may download the sample and migrate the code to a sample MVC5 app to give it a try. If I can get some time, I will try to provide a sample but don't wait on me !!!

Answer (score 0):

[Datatables.net](http://datatables.net/reference/index) has documentation on their site. You can start with the [References](http://datatables.net/reference/index) page.

Use nuget package manager in VS and download it from there or get it from the site it's self. Include the following in your project:

`~/Scripts/DataTables-x.x.x/jquery.dataTables.js`

`~/Content/DataTables-x.x.x/css/jquery.datatables.css`

**Basic configuration:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

**Now you can build a basic html table from your data:**

```
@* Do we have data to show? *@
        @if (Model.Count > 1)
        {
            int resultCount = 0;

            <table id="inventoryResultsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-tag"></i>&nbsp;Asset #</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>&nbsp;Type</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-cube"></i>&nbsp;Asset Name</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>&nbsp;Manufacturer</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>&nbsp;Model</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i>&nbsp;Serial #</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>&nbsp;Add. Info</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>&nbsp;In Use</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>&nbsp;Purpose</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>&nbsp;Location</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>&nbsp;Options</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>

                     @* Iterate and build data rows with avalible data *@
                     @foreach (var Asset in Model)
                     {
                        resultCount++;
                        string assetNumberDisplay = Asset.AssetNumber.ToString() == "0" ? "Unknown" : Asset.AssetNumber.ToString("D4");
                        string assetInUseDisplay = Asset.InUse == true ? "Yes" : "No";

                        <tr>
                            <td>@assetNumberDisplay</td>
                            <td>@Asset.AssetType</td>
                            <td>@Asset.AssetName</td>
                            <td>@Asset.Manufacturer</td>
                            <td>@Asset.Model</td>
                            <td>@Asset.SerialNumber</td>
                            <td>@Asset.AdditionalInfo</td>
                            <td>@assetInUseDisplay</td>
                            <td>@Asset.Purpose</td>
                            <td>@Asset.Location</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/Inventory/AssetDetails/" + Asset.Id + "' id='" + Asset.Id + "' title='Edit'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> </span> </a>")
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/Inventory/DeleteAsset/" + Asset.Id + "' id='" + Asset.Id + "' title='Delete'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span> </a>")
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                           }

                 </tbody>

             </table>
         }
         else
         {
             @* Alert User that there was no data found to display based on constraints set  *@
             <h4><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;<b>0</b>&nbsp;Results Found</h4>
             <hr />
             <p>Your search did not return any results. You can try searching again using differant constraints.</p>
         }
```

**Making it responsive:**

Now you can make your table responsive by using the nice 'responsive' plugin that they have included in the package:

`~/Scripts/DataTables-x.x.x/dataTables.responsive.min.js`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
          responsive: true
        });
    });
```

There are many other options as well, such as custom sorting options and customizing the number of records per page. Try using the Google search built into their site.

Perhaps a better solution than datatables.mvc would be to use something like [MVC Jquery Datatables](https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables) as it allows you to use data from IQueryables. The latter lacks documentation but this project has a bit more example to it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i read about MVC Jquery Datatables but i could not figure out how to work with it,, as i could not find any full documentations about it ,, can you adivce ?

Comment: @johnG the documentation from MVC Jquery Datatables is here... http://aspdatatables.azurewebsites.net/ .. you'll just have to follow the documentation on the page and modify according to your needs. I know its not as detailed as would like but it's probably one of the better solutions for DT.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, canSort: true,rowsPerPage:1);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious,nextText:"Next",previousText:"Prev",numericLinksCount:1);
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid",headerStyle:"header", columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("name", "Name", canSort: true),
grid.Column("address", "Address"), grid.Column("gender", "Gender"), grid.Column("age", "Age"),
grid.Column("mob", "Mobile"), grid.Column(format: @<text><a id="link" href='@Url.Action("Details", "Admin", new { @email = item.email })'>@item.email</a></text>)));
```

Comment: Providing some explanation to the code is recommended while answering on SO